WordPress Create New Role Just to Manage Users?
I'm trying to create a new role where the only thing this role can do is manage/add/edit/delete users in the admin.
    add_role('test_role', 'TEST Role', array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_users' => true,
        'add_users' => true,
        'create_users' => true,
        'delete_users' => true,
        'list_users' => true,
        'promote_users' => true,
        'remove_users' => true,
    ));

I must be missing something, after running this code and creating a new user with that role I can't login to the admin, It just redirects to the frontend of the site.
Any ideas?

I can't access the admin area with this user, does anyone know what else needs added to the above code?

Just found out the above code isn't working because of WooCommerce, that is odd!
